# asp:DropdownList not firing for SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I change the selection of my dropdown, the Change event does not fire.  I put a breakpoint in the method and the program does not stop.

This is my markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div style='text-align:center;'>
        <a style='text-decoration:none;font-size:16px;color:blue;background-color:white;width:200px;padding:4px;' href='LocationDetails.aspx?Location_ID=0' target='detailPanel'> Add Location
        </a></div>
        &nbsp
        <div style='text-align:left;'>
            <asp:Label ID="FacilityTypeLbl" runat="server">Facility Type:</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="FacilityTypeDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FacilityTypeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <hr/>
     <%ListLocations()%>   
 </form>
```

This is my Page_Load method to populate the list and it works fine.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            GetServiceTypes()
            FacilityTypeDDL.DataSource = dtServiceTypes
            FacilityTypeDDL.DataTextField = dtServiceTypes.Columns("Title").ToString()
            FacilityTypeDDL.DataValueField = dtServiceTypes.Columns("ID").ToString()
            FacilityTypeDDL.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

This is my change event:

```
 Protected Sub FacilityTypeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FacilityTypeDDL.SelectedIndexChanged
        strFacilityValue = FacilityTypeDDL.SelectedValue
        ListLocations()
End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint at the first line of code and after changing the dropdown selection it does not stop at this event.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
This is my entire markup.  Can there be something wrong this it?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Locations.aspx.vb" Inherits="Editor_Locations" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="LocationHead" runat="server">
    <title>Locations</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>   
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">        
        <div style='text-align:left;'>
            <asp:Label ID="FacilityTypeLbl" runat="server">Facility Type:</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="FacilityTypeDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FacilityTypeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Test34</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <hr/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
This application is a web site, not a web application. (I didn't know there was a difference but now I do.) In trying to figure out way the SelectedIndexChange event will not fire, I added a button and a click event.  When I change the selection in the dropdown list, no event fires.  When I click the button, the click event fires, then the selectedindexchange event fires.

I don't think the event SelectedIndexChanged is going to work.

Is there any other way to wire up a Postback when the dropdown list changes? 
Can I somehow use __doPostback from a javascript function call when the list changes?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is AutoEventWireup="true" set on your .aspx Page directive?

Comment: It was set to 'false'.  I set it to 'true' and it still is not firing the event.

Comment: Have you tried `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` this for your `DropdownList`?

Comment: Yes.  I added that attribute and still no worky

Comment: The above markup works for me when I have added `ListItem` in aspx page. Commenting the Page_Load code and try to add some items in html markup and check again.

Comment: Does your dropdownlist have more than 1 entry and does it behave the same no matter which you click? I had a similar issue with a ddl and noticed that the selected index did not in fact change since it was 1 by default on load and I only had 1 real item and a "Make selection" text on it..

Comment: I have 17 items in the list.  I select a different item and I have a breakpoint in the event method and it does not stop there and the menu list does not change.

Comment: @SelvaTS - I tried your suggestion and the event **still** does not fire! I commented out the Page_load code and added to items to the list.  Selected the second item and still does not hit the event!

Comment: I have just put your html markup without any other code and added some list items and its working for me. So try to check remaining portions of your html markup.

Comment: This is so aggravating!!! I only have the dropdown in the markup.  I added 3 items to the list.  The event is **still not firing**...What could it possibly be?

Comment: This web site is an older version of aspx.  .NET 2.0 would that matter?

Comment: @SelvaTS - Could you post your markup?

Comment: The same markup whatever you have posted here. `<asp:DropDownList ID="FacilityTypeDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="FacilityTypeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Test0</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Test1</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: I added my entire markup above.  Can you copy that to your IDE and see if it works?

Comment: When I add events in C#, they always work.  I have to be missing something.

Comment: I got compiler error and I have changed `CodeBehind` instead of `CodeFile` and its worked for me.

Comment: when I change CodeFile to CodeBehind, I get a compile error: Could not load type Editor_Locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the asp:DropdownList to fire the SelectedIndexChanged event.  So this is how I completed the task.

Adding the dropdown dynamically as shown above and adding the change event that calls a javascript:

```
 onchange='UpdateLocationList()'
```

This function had to be put in a .js file. This web site had a .js file already.  It also had some AJAX calls that I used to complete the task.
In the UpdateLocationList(), I get the ID of the service type that was set as a value attribute in the dropdown. Then I use a function that is already part of the .js file to the LocationDetails page using the Service Type ID to display only the facilities of that service type.  This is the function:

```
    function updateLocationList() {
    var ddlFacilityType = document.getElementById("FacilityTypeDDL");
    var facilityValue = ddlFacilityType.options[ddlFacilityType.selectedIndex].value;
    processAjax("/editor/Locations.aspx?Location_ID=" + facilityValue, "navPanel");
}
```

Works like a charm.

Thanks for all of your help.